# Cannot Delete Files and Directories at the same time

Tags: c#, compact-framework, delete-file

Im working on compact framework 3.5. I can delete files by using `File.Delete()` and can delete directories by using my method.

Here is the problem : I can call only `File.Delete()` methods or my directory deleting method (which name is DD). They both works but not work together. Here is my code :

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Reset_Client
{
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string path = @"\Storage Card\deneme\";



        File.Delete(path + "Agentry.ini");
        File.Delete(path + "Agentry.app");
        File.Delete(path + "Agentry.usr");
        //DF(path);
        DD(path);


        MessageBox.Show("Cihaz resetlendi!");
    }

    public static void DD(string mainPath)
    {
        try
        {
            DeleteDirectory(mainPath + "CRM");
            DeleteDirectory(mainPath + "BHTS");
            DeleteDirectory(mainPath + "IMAGES");
            DeleteDirectory(mainPath + "STYLES");
            DeleteDirectory(mainPath + "TABLES");
            DeleteDirectory(mainPath + "LOG");

        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            DD(mainPath);
        }
    }
    //public static void DF(string mainPath)
    //{
    //    try
    //    {
    //        DeleteFile(mainPath + "Agentry.ini");
    //        DeleteFile(mainPath + "Agentry.app");
    //        DeleteFile(mainPath + "Agentry.usr");
    //    }
    //    catch (IOException e)
    //    {
    //        DF(mainPath);
    //    }
    //}


    public static void DeleteDirectory(string target_dir)
    {
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(target_dir);
        FileAttributes attributes = fileInfo.Attributes;

        if ((attributes & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) == FileAttributes.ReadOnly)
        {
            // set the attributes to nonreadonly
            fileInfo.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
        }

        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(target_dir);
        string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(target_dir);

        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            File.Delete(file);
        }

        foreach (string dir in dirs)
        {
            DeleteDirectory(dir);
        }

        Directory.Delete(target_dir, false);
    }

    public static void DeleteFile(string target_dir)
    {
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(target_dir);
        FileAttributes attributes = fileInfo.Attributes;

        if ((attributes & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) == FileAttributes.ReadOnly)
        {
            // set the attributes to nonreadonly
            fileInfo.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
        }



    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please define "not work together".

Comment: In main ;

it works if i call only 

        File.Delete(path + "Agentry.ini");
        File.Delete(path + "Agentry.app");
        File.Delete(path + "Agentry.usr");  it deletes files.

or it works if i call only  
              
                     DD(path);

but it does not work when i call all of them.

Comment: Can you expand on "does not work" - does it throw an exception, what's the error message, etc?

Comment: No error message , DD method deletes directories but File.Delete() methods dont delete that 3files.

Answer (score 0):

The following *may* be your problem.

Typically you can only delete empty directories. Your `DD` function would have to recurse down the directory path, find all the files, and call `File.Delete` on them, before deleting the directory that enclosed them.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Directory.Delete(target_dir, true) replace your DD method to delete directory directly. The second arg is true,means recursive.
Another point. If any IO exception occurs. The DD method catch the exception and call DD method again. It will be a dead loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippit I have. I cannot remember if I got it from somewhere or if I wrote it. This should do what you are wanting to do

```
 public void ClearFolder(string folderName)  
 {  
   DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(folderName);  
   foreach (FileInfo fi in dir.GetFiles())  
   {  
     fi.Delete();  
   }  
   foreach (DirectoryInfo di in dir.GetDirectories())  
   {  
     ClearFolder(di.FullName);  
     di.Delete();  
   }  
 }
```

I would try it like this and see if it works.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Reset_Client
{
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string path = @"\Storage Card\deneme\";
        File.Delete(path + "Agentry.ini");
        File.Delete(path + "Agentry.app");
        File.Delete(path + "Agentry.usr");
        //DF(path);
        DD(path);
        MessageBox.Show("Cihaz resetlendi!");
    }

    public static void DD(string mainPath)
    {
        try
        {
            ClearFolder(mainPath + "CRM");
            ClearFolder(mainPath + "BHTS");
            ClearFolder(mainPath + "IMAGES");
            ClearFolder(mainPath + "STYLES");
            ClearFolder(mainPath + "TABLES");
            ClearFolder(mainPath + "LOG");

        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            DD(mainPath);
        }
    }

    public void ClearFolder(string folderName)  
    {  
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(folderName);  
        foreach (FileInfo fi in dir.GetFiles())  
        {  
            fi.Delete();  
        }  
        foreach (DirectoryInfo di in dir.GetDirectories())  
        {  
            ClearFolder(di.FullName);  
            di.Delete();  
        }  
    }  
}
}
```